# Detect that an option (any) has been selected

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering how to throw an alert when i select an option of a select. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/v4ep2/) is my try:

**HTML**

```
<select id="provinces">
    <option>aaa</option>
    <option>bbb</option>
    <option>ccc</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$('#provinces').click(function(){
    alert("test");
});
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<select id="provinces">
    <option>aaa</option>
    <option>bbb</option>
    <option>ccc</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#provinces').change(function(){

    //Any of these will work

    alert($("#provinces option:selected").val());

    alert($("option:selected",this).val());

    alert($(this).find("option:selected").val());

    alert($(this).val());

    //or without the aid of jQuery, simply...
    alert(this.value);
});
```

**Edit:**

Thanks for the edit @Splash-X, here is the documentation for using [Selector Context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context). For argument sake, I've added a few different alternatives but the first one would be the worst as it has no context and selects from the entire DOM. The second option actually uses the third option underneath.

Comment: @user1077220 it looks like you do not have jQuery selected in your jsFiddle. Try changing the slection in the drop down, currently Mootools is selected.

Comment: @Sol I believe that you may be mistaken. Which browser/version is it not working in for jQuery 1.7? Have a look at the docs for [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: @Sol no worries at all. I make mistakes on the regular ;-) cheers

Comment: @Splash-X nice edit removing the ID selector, I never do it that way but now the `option:selected` selector will work on the `#provinces` object we already have, making it perform better (even though a mild gain), correct?

Comment: @Craig  Correct, there is an alternative way to do it as well: $(this).find('option:selected').val(); Either way you eliminate the need to re-specify what element to look in. If your "change" selector was for more than one element you'd be in a pickel if you were trying to specify the selector inside of the function.

Comment: @FelixKling I think that is the best suggestion. I am fluent in JavaScript and jQuery but am trying to fine tune my literacy and I appreciate your comment. +1